# How can I modify the values of an array within a function and then use the "new" array where the function was called

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, reference

So for part of my homework I need to make a yahtzee style text game. At the moment I am working on an array to hold the dice values. My issue is being able to pass an array into a function to modify values, and then use that modified array again. Initially I wanted to do it with references or pointers. I had issues with doing it that way and I haven't been able to get either way to compile. Today I talked to my teacher who told me that arrays can be modified normally inside of a function and then used again, essentially saying that they are passed by reference automatically.

Can someone please clarify what my teacher means and if it is correct. Also, what method would you guys recommend. Below is my current implementation attempting to use references

```
/******************************************************
** Function: runGame
** Description: Runs game and keeps track of players
** Parameters: # of players
** Pre-Conditions: c is an integer from 1 to 9
** Post-Conditions:
******************************************************/
void runGame(int players) {
    Player p = new Player[players]; //needs to be deleted at the end
    int dice[] = { -1, -1, -1, -1, -1 };
    int category; // used to hold category chosen
    while (isGameOver(p)) {
        for (int i = 0; i < players; i++) {
            rollDice(dice); //uses reference
            p[i].scoreBoard= updateScore(p[i], dice);
            p[i].catsLeft--;
        }
    }
}

/******************************************************
** Function: rollDice
** Description: rolls dice, prints array and either rerolls
** Parameters: int[] dice
** Pre-Conditions:
** Post-Conditions:
******************************************************/
void rollDice(int (&dice) [5]) {
    int again;
    string indices; // indices of dice to reroll
    cout << "Your dice are" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        dice[i] = rand() % (6) + 1;
        cout << dice[i];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        cout << "Roll again? Type anything except 0 to go again." << endl;
        cin >> again;

        if (again) {
            cout << "Type each index without a space that you would like to reroll";
            cin.ignore();
            getline(cin, indices);
            for (int i = 0; i < indices.length(); i++) {
                dice[(int)indices[i] - '0'] = rand() % (6) + 1;
            }
        }
        else
            break;
    }

}
```

At the moment I am getting compiler errors saying

> error: no match for ‘operator[]’ (operand types are ‘Player’ and
>   ‘int’)
>       p[i].scoreBoard= updateScore(p[i], dice);

And consequent ones for the other times I attempt to use p[i]

Comment: 'p' should be a pointer to Player. The line initialising it probably should not compile.

Comment: `Player p` isn't a pointer. Use `Player *p` instead.

Comment: Sidenote: Your teacher probably has it on the "Do Not Use" list for now, but look up `std::vector`. It solves the bulk of the problems you will encounter with dynamically allocated arrays.

Answer (score 1):

What your teacher meant that you can pass an array to another function as a pointer and use this to modify the values inside the array in another function. Use the following example to check the values printed before modifying the array and after modifying it. Note how the array is being passed from main funtion to modifyArray funtion.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void modifyArray(int * arr, int len)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        arr[i] += 1;
    }

}

void printArr(int *arr, int len)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        cout << arr[i];
    }
    cout << endl;
}

int main()
{
    int arr[5] = { 1,2,3,4,5 };
    cout << "Before :" << endl;
    printArr(arr, 5);    
    modifyArray(arr, 5);    
    cout << endl << "After : " << endl;
    printArr(arr, 5);    
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What your teacher means is that if you have a pointer with a buffer integers and with that always hold the values.

Ex:

```
int* p = new int[5];
```

This will create an array with 5 slots now everytime you fill it it will always change, there are some things that can be a little bit different if you are doing object oriented but mostly it will be like that. You can use is as a global variable for testing.

The way you can move around it is by writing either p[slot number you want]. This way will make it possible for you to use the array, another way is to return the array with the numbers(instead of having void).